# What melee weapons would a person with metal arm (up to shoulders) and leg (above the knees) prosthetics use?

Tags: cyborg, melee

As the title says, working on a story with a character who has mechanical prosthetics but has to have some sort of melee weapon(s). He would have better strength than an average human, but isn't *that* much heavier, so swinging around something weighing a ton is a no go for inertia reasons. At first I thought something perhaps like bladed tonfa's since he'd be able to hold the edges totally safely if need be, but would that be utilizing all the advantages that these prosthetics could potentially bring to the table? For example, it'd be like permanent armor without the worry of pain or permanent damage, so presumably defense isn't a huge issue, and grip strength is totally superhuman so there's no need to worry of slipping exactly, even if "half-swording" is implemented.

Assuming weapon material isn't an issue in regards to failing (breaking, chipping, dulling, etc), what would you all suggest?

Comment: So what are those "advantages" that this prosthetic could potentially bring? This is very opinion-based nad open question. and most of the answer would be identical to question "my character is very strong, what weapon they can use?"

Comment: It sounds like this individual is capable of wielding any weapon a normal human can. There are a lot of melee weapons to choose from and selecting the "best" is highly context dependent. This is probably better treated as an opportunity to characterize this individual rather than a world building challenge.

Comment: The obvious problem with your "bladed tonfas" suggestion is, of course, that holding the bladed part  with a material they could not cut would blunt them.  Then you just have "weirdly shaped tonfas" instead.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question, as written, isn't a good match for Stack Exchange forums. Here, we deal with questions that help you build or devise your fictional world --- its underlying mechanics, systems & fundamentals. Basically, how things work and how they got that way. Your question is a matter of character choice -- basically, whatever melee weapon she wants to pick up. Please take a look at our [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea what this forum is about and what kinds of questions work and don't work here!

Comment: I think potentially you should look at some of the ninja martial arts weapons, because the things a cyborg could do differently than anyone else would be to have small, flexible (monofilament?) weapons mounted and concealed in his cyber-limbs. Look also at Wolverine, and the blades from Deus Ex. Garrots, chain-whips, etc. the list is endless.

Answer (score 1):

A heavy rapier

Assuming he has a high arm strength (but normal chest muscles) and high arm stamina, he can be a relentless fencer. His powered leg can give him an extra advantage in fencing.

Comment: Fascinating, I had never considered a heavy rapier! I was more fixated on the armored/lack of pain aspect of having these prosthetics and discounting the strength/stamina that would be afforded by them.

Comment: +1 for taking into account that chest, back and stomach muscles are all normal.